# owl carousel stop showing images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, owl-carousel

Add owl carousel css and js:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css
```

Owl carousel stop showing images, but earlier it was working correctly. I haven't changed anything in code before.

Here is JavaScript and HTML code:

```js
var carouselLite = function() {

        var owl5 = $(".owl-carousel5");

        owl5.owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            margin: 0,
            center: false,
            responsiveClass: true,
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            dots: true,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 500,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    nav:false
                },
                480: {
                    nav:false
                },
                768:{
                    nav:false
                },
                1000:{
                    nav:true,
                }
            },
            navText: [
                "<i class='icon-arrow-left owl-direction'></i>",
                "<i class='icon-arrow-right owl-direction'></i>"
            ]
        });
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel5">
    <div class="item"><img src="images/draft_duo_1.png" alt="Draft Duo 1"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/draft_duo_2.png" alt="Draft Duo 2"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/draft_duo_3.png" alt="Draft Duo 3"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="images/draft_duo_4.png" alt="Draft Duo 4"></div>
</div>
```

[This is site photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pMYv.png)

Comment: Kindly add the Owl carousel 's CSS/JS.

Comment: I add owl carousel's CSS/JS yet

Comment: Add the `script` and the `stylesheet` preferably via cdn for the version of owl carousel you're using.